# mouseover is not working properly when I am create a tag dynamically using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to assign mouseover effect in my input tag.but when I am try to hover mouse on any input tag it will affect on all input tag.

```
<td *ngFor="let d of Xyz">
    <input class="inputLabel" size="3" type="text" value="XYZ"  (mouseover)="hover = true" (mouseleave)="hover = false" [ngClass]="{inputCls: hover}"/>
</td>
```

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/649/ //here is working Fine in Angular 1.* version but I want to do same thing in 2.0 but its not working.

Here I have added input tags statically but I am creating this tags using *ngFor in Angular js.

I want to do mouseover effect in only which tag is over.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that :

```
<div ng-app>
  <input class="inputLabel" size="3" type="text" value="Xyz"  ng-mouseover="hover0 = true" ng-mouseleave="hover0 = false" ng-Class="{inputCls: hover0}"/>

  <input class="inputLabel" size="3" type="text" value="Xyz"  ng-mouseover="hover1 = true" ng-mouseleave="hover1 = false" ng-Class="{inputCls: hover1}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: i am creating it dynamically using *ng-for so its always hover.Any Other Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First, the behavior you are seeing is expected. since all elements would change class based on `hover`, if any of them changes the hover to true then all will get the inputCls and would display in hover mode.

Now, if we want them to behave independently, we need to have the ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave set an attribute that is specific to this element, and inputCls to depend on that element-specific attribute.

by using something like `<input *ng-for="#el of list; #idx = index"` you will get the idx set to the serial number for the element, and can use that to create an element specific variable that your mouseover and mouseleave can set and clear.

Comment: sorry but I am new in angular js can please give some example of this..

Answer (score 0):

Mouseover behavior is OK here. The problem is that your solution sets a *hover* atribute in the whole current scope. You need to have separate atributes for each tag. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/648/

```
<input class="inputLabel" size="3" type="text" value="Xyz"  ng-mouseover="hover1 = true" ng-mouseleave="hover1 = false" ng-Class="{inputCls: hover1}"/>

<input class="inputLabel" size="3" type="text" value="Xyz"  ng-mouseover="hover2 = true" ng-mouseleave="hover2 = false" ng-Class="{inputCls: hover2}"/>
```

BTW: you are probably not using AngularJS but Angular2. See this [ngFor documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!#stq=ngFor&stp=1) with [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVuXxDp0qinGDyo307QW?p=preview).